# How to show linear transformation $T$ is bijective based on the following assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $T:P_n(\Bbb{R})\rightarrow P_n(\Bbb{R})$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x))=p(x)+p'(x)$ where $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$. Show that $T$ is bijective.

Here is my try:

Let  $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.  Then $T(p(x))=p(x)+p'(x)=ax^2+(2a+b)x+(c+b)$. Clearly $\dim V=\dim W=3$, so we only have to show either injectivity or surjectivity. Since $T$ is injective if $T(p(x))\in$ Ker$(T)$ (Not sure if such way of saying is correct), we solve the system $(a, 2a+b, c+b)=(0,0,0)$ and we get $a=b=c=0$. So the $T(p(x))\in$ Ker$(T)$. Therefore $T$ is bijective. But how do we confirm its surjectivity if we really want to know?

Here comes the new problem: what if we let $T(p(x))=p(x)+a_1p'(x)+...+a_np^{(n)}(x)$ where $a_1,...,a_n$ are scalars and $p^{(k)}(x)$ is the $k$th derivative of $p(x)$. How do we show $T$ is bijective?

The $\dim$ of $V$ should equal $\dim$ of $W$ as I tried various terms, but I have hard time expressing such thing. In addition, How are we going to show its injectivity?

Comment: You seem to be very confused. First, of course we have $V = W = P_n(\mathbb R)$. This is in the definition of $T$. Second, your proof is correct. Only this "$T(p(x))\in\ker(T)$" is not correct. Injectivity is equivalent to $\ker(T) = \{0\}$. Third, you have not proved the general statement that $T$ is injective for arbitrary $n$. You have only proved it for $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T(p) = 0$, then
$p$ satisfies the equation
$\sum_k a_k p^{(k)} (x) = 0$ for all $x$; we have $a_0 = 1$.

Note that for all $p \in \mathbb{P}_n$, we have that $p^{(n)} $ is a constant.

Differentiate the equation $\sum_k a_k p^{(k)} (x) = 0$ $n$ times, and since
$a_0 = 1$, we see that $p^{(n)} = 0$.

Now differentiate the equation $n-1$ times, we see that $p^{(n-1)} = 0$.

Repeating we see that $p = 0$.

If you want to show surjectivity (indeed, this shows injectivity too),
suppose $T(p) = y$.
If we differentiate both sides $n$ times and evaluate at $x=0$, we
see that $p^{(n)}(0) = y^{(n)}(0)$.
Now differentiate both sides $n-1$ times and evaluate at $x=0$ to get
$p^{(n-1)}(0)+ a_1 p^{(n)}(0) = y^{(n-1)}(0)$, which gives $p^{(n-1)}(0)$.
Repeating (this is a 'triangular' system) gives values for $p^{(k)}(0)$ for
$k=0,...,n$. This uniquely defines the polynomial $p$. Hence $T$ is surjective and injective.